# Form without movement when filling in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use a DataGridView as a console for an application, I need to fill it out every second, I use the following code for this:

```
public class dgView
{
    public static DataGridView DataConsole;

    public static void addLinha(int tipo_acao, string acao, string extra, int tipo_extra)
    {
        // INSERE LINHA NO CONSOLE
        try
        {
            if (DataConsole == null) return;

            var idLinha = DataConsole.Rows.Add();
            using (var linha = DataConsole.Rows[idLinha])
            {
                //await Task.Delay(300);

                if (tipo_acao == 0)
                {
                    linha.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Teal;
                    linha.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                }
                else if (tipo_acao == 1)
                {
                    linha.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    linha.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                }
                else
                {
                    linha.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    linha.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = Color.Magenta;
                }


                linha.Cells["dg_data"].Value = DateTime.Now;
                linha.Cells["dg_mapa"].Value = "" + Config.Mapa + "";
                linha.Cells["dg_acao"].Value = "" + Config.rm.GetString("" + acao + "") + "";
                if (tipo_extra == 0)
                {
                    linha.Cells["dg_extra"].Value = "" + extra + "";
                }
                else
                {
                    linha.Cells["dg_extra"].Value = "" + Config.rm.GetString(extra) + "";
                }

                DataConsole.CurrentCell = DataConsole.Rows[idLinha].Cells[0];
                //DataConsole.Refresh();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the form freezes and I can't move it to any part of the screen, would there be any way to solve this? Remembering that the DataGridView is not, and cannot be populated through the `DataSource` property, but by a constant verification in the system.

Example:

```
public static void Abrir(string metodoChamador)
{
    try
    {
       Abrir:
        dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Abrir", "config_Validando", 1);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Atalho:
        string AtalhoExiste = "" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Config.Atalho + ".lnk";
        if (!File.Exists(AtalhoExiste))
        {
            dgView.addLinha(2, "config_FaltaIcone", "", 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            goto Atalho;
        }
        else
        {

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Config.Atalho + ".lnk");
            Process whatever = Process.Start(info);
            whatever.Dispose();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            IntPtr WinHandle = Win32.FindWindow(null, Config.Atalho);
            
            if (WinHandle == (IntPtr)0)
            {
                goto Abrir;
            }
 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialize and use your DGV? Why is everything `static`? Maybe because *`static` is thread-safe*? (unrelated: you can remove that `DataConsol.Refresh();`, that control *refreshes* itself). + What does * fill it out every second* mean? Clear it and re-fill it? Add a new Row? Other. + Is the parent Form initialized from a Console app?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I said, the DGV works as a console, without `DataConsol.Refresh ();` it is not updated in real time, it takes a few seconds for the new lines to appear. The DGV is started empty, without data, I insert data using the above method as necessary during the execution of the program.

Comment: Can you give more details about the context of your operations? *the DGV works as a console* doesn't mean anything. You didn't answer the other questions. + As already mentioned, the DGV doesn't require to call `Refresh()` when a new Row is added, it does that on its own. If it doesn't, that's a symptom that's another something isn't working as the way it should, hence the need of more details.

Comment: Hello there. You could make the caller `async` method and just after calling `addrow(...)` method, add `await Task.Delay(300);`. Where `300` is time in milliseconds to wait before calling the `addrow(...)` again. And yes as mentioned, don't call `.Refresh`. This way, the Form won't freeze.

Comment: I'm researching async, all the ways I find are examples with a database, no way to popularize DGV the way I need it.

Comment: Could you please paste the caller? Where you call `addrow(...)` static method.

Comment: `dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Fechado", "config_Validando", 1);`

Comment: As it is here, I was trying to make async work, but with it I am not inserting anything.

Comment: Add the `async` modifier to the signature: `public async static void addLinha(...) { ... }` and uncomment `await Task.Delay(300);`. You have strange calls pattern buddy :)

Comment: What matters here is how you're using this class. What calls it, where it's called. It appears that you're trying to use this Control from other threads. If that's the case, there you have your problem. The overall context where you're using this class is still obscure. How the DGV is built or how you add a Row is not relevant, the way it's used is.

Comment: It did not work, are not entering any data in the DGV after placing async.

Comment: Now give us the method where you call this `dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Fechado", "config_Validando", 1);` ? Paste all the relevant code to understand this chain of calls.

Comment: Sorry mate, but this code needs a _Da Capo_ to be written again.  I understand now that you need to call this method `public static void Abrir(string metodoChamador) {..}` every 5 seconds or so. If that's accurate, then you could use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to call it instead of the `goto` way. No one uses `goto` anymore in high-level programming.

Comment: But about the freezing of the form, is it related to the goto? I believe that even if you remove it, you will still lock the form when trying to fill out the DGV.

Comment: Because of this `Thread.Sleep(5000);`. This is preventing the UI from being refreshed/repainted/re-anything else. Anyways, someone could suggest some improvements, so be patient please. Lunch Time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell if you have other potential problems in the code.   Basically anywhere you have `Thread.Sleep()`, your GUI is going to freeze.

Here's a possible refactoring of your `Abrir()` method, using `async\await` and `Task.Delay()` as suggested by JQSOFT:

```
public async static void Abrir(string metodoChamador)
{
    try
    {
        IntPtr WinHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        do
        {
            dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Abrir", "config_Validando", 1);
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            string AtalhoExiste = "" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Config.Atalho + ".lnk";
            while (!File.Exists(AtalhoExiste))
            {
                dgView.addLinha(2, "config_FaltaIcone", "", 0);
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Config.Atalho + ".lnk");
            Process whatever = Process.Start(info);
            whatever.Dispose();
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            WinHandle = Win32.FindWindow(null, Config.Atalho);
        }
        while (WinHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

If you have `Thread.Sleep()` in other locations, they would need to be refactored.
If you have any other infinite loops using `goto`, those may need to be refactored as well.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Another day of learning in the C # course in practice, I learned 3 more things today, thank you very much.

Comment: Note that there are no labels/`goto`s in the refactored code.  It is always possible to rewrite code using `goto` with some kind of loop(s).  In general, using a loop is going to be easier to read, follow, and understand.  The process of writing the loop also helps you determine what conditions the loop should or should not continue as well.